# How to save selected value in dropdownlist in MVC-4 after submit?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

How to save chosen value in dropdownlist after submit. So the value that you choose in dropdownlist stays after user click on submit.

In my controller I did this:

```
List<SelectListItem> uraList = new List<SelectListItem>();

for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++)
{
    uraList.Add(new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = i + ":00",
        Text = i + ":00"
    });
}

ViewBag.IzberiUro = uraList;
ViewBag.IzbranaUra = model.Ura;
```

In my Model (I think that here is mistake):

```
public string Ura { get; set; }
```

And in View I have:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Ura", ((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.IzberiUro).Select(t => new SelectListItem() {Text = t.Text, Value = t.Text,Selected = (t.Text == ViewBag.IzbranaUra)}), new {@class = "css"})
```

The result is, in view I have dropdownlist with values from 1:00 to 6:00 (whitch is correct, and first choosen value is 1:00), but, when I choose e.g. 4:00 and click on submit, the value in dropdown returns to 1:00.

Realy thanks for help.

---

my generated HTML is then like this:

```
<select class="form-control" id="Ura" name="Ura" placeholder="Ura" style="width: 100px;">
  <option value="1:00">1:00</option>
  <option value="2:00">2:00</option>
  <option value="3:00">3:00</option>
  <option value="4:00">4:00</option>
  <option value="5:00">5:00</option>
  <option value="6:00">6:00</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you share generated html code?

Comment: I post it in my question... I hope I post correct code...

Comment: I solved, the problem was, That I did not call correct model in Controller, so my model of "Ura" was always empty. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DropDownListFor` instead of `DropDownList`

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Ura, Model.uraList)
```

Comment: I upvote your ansewer, I figureout how to call it, and it works. But solution for my problem was, that I did not call correct Model in Controller, so it was always empty...

Comment: You havent post the controller code to figure it out by myself :)